# Implementing threading while making a GUI that reads Serial Data and plots Graphs

Tags: c#, multithreading, graph, serial-port, backgroundworker

I'm in the middle of a project wherein I have to read Serial Data in CSV format from the sensors of an Arduino , parse the obtained values using C#, and  display real time graphs.

I am new to the concept of multithreading and I'm confused about how many threads should I make, and what task each thread should be assigned.

Any Suggestions?
This is an initial sample code, so it may have errors.

```
 private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        RxString = RxString.Replace("$", "");
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));

    }
    //display the parsed string List
    private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        richTextBox1.AppendText(RxString);
        GlobalList.AddRange(parsed());
        richTextBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, GlobalList);
    }
    //set the input rate
    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM32";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.DtrEnable=true;
        serialPort1.Open();
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            Start.Enabled = false;
            Stop.Enabled = true;
            richTextBox1.ReadOnly = false;

        }

    }
 public List<String> parsed()
    {
                string line;
                int loc = 0;
                List<string> stringList;
                line = richTextBox1.Text;
                stringList = new List<string>(line.Split(','));
                richTextBox3.AppendText("\n Pressure:" + stringList[loc]);
                loc++;
                richTextBox3.AppendText("\n Accelerometer:" + stringList[loc]);
                loc++;
                richTextBox3.AppendText("\n Temperature:" + stringList[loc]);
                loc++;
                richTextBox3.AppendText("\n Height:" + stringList[loc]);
                loc++;


            return stringList;
    }

//plot an elementary graph from the values obtained
public void displayglobal()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < GlobalList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                rtxtConsole.AppendText("\nPressure: " + GlobalList[i]);
                chart1.Series["tempvspressure"].Points.AddXY(GlobalList[i], GlobalList[i + 2]);
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some more info please? Maybe some code samples from what you have so far?

Comment: Is there an actual problem with your code?  Does it not work?

Comment: No, I don't have any issues with the code. My problem is that I cannot decide how to implement multithreading on this code. Should I use a BackgroundWorker to fetch the serial data while the graphs are being plotted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly advise using a worker thread on anything that can block, since this freezes up the UI.

I would spin off a single thread to read the incoming stream and parse units of data. If the stream is CSV then your row delimiter, usually a new line, can be used by the stream parser to delimit units.

If the workload per row is very low, the stream reading thread can just invoke the UI thread for handling each time it has a complete unit of data. If the number of rows being handled causes the UI  to lock up then another worker thread may be desired to batch insert them into the UI. For this you would require a thread safe queue.

I've done this many times in logging applications which listen to a network stream and the problem doesn't seem that different for a serial port.

Answer (score 0):

With the new `async` support in C#, you shouldn't need multiple threads at all.

You can use `port.BaseStream.ReadAsync()` which will cooperate with UI message processing.